# Substitute/Replacement for WeakReferenceMonitor

Tags: spring, deprecated

So I've been using [WeakReferenceMonitor](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/WeakReferenceMonitor.html) for a while.

It was however, deprecated in 4.3.6 and has now been removed in Spring 5.

Was wondering if anyone has an idea of what I can use to replace this? Also, I can't really find any discussion on why it was deprecated...

Comment: Sadly the documentation doesn't suggest a suitable replacement.

Comment: Yeah I guess just extracting the code and holding it locally is the best solution